# 3rd party private API key get from the user on the client end and stored in db - how to make it safe?

Tags: django, reactjs, security

I am working on a django+react project that requires 3rd party private API key.

My idea is, that user provides the private key once logged in to my app and the key is stored in the django's db and using it requires the user to be authenticated an authorized.

I would make the API calls using the private key on the server side.

However, I am wondering if I should extra secure the process of providing the key on the client side - ex. if the key can be stolen when being provided by the user as an input and before it gets stored in the db, where is should be safe as I understand.

What steps should I take, to make the api key providing process safe?

Comment: wow, this is a really broad question. In short, and generally speaking, follow good practices. You page should at minimum provide encrypted transmission of the key, HTTPS is normally enough. You need to make sure it is a human actually going through the process. Using a token to validated that the request is legit for the web session is a need to have. Looking for the usual, XSS, CSRF..A code review should help a lot here..

Comment: Thanks Victor, this is exactly what I needed - the main concern was if should go for something on top of following good practices. Cheers

Comment: Oauth2 is designed for this very puepose, to allow a 3rd party (you) to use a service on behalf of a user. Storing a user's private key is risky and bad design. You can't really make this secure, because it's fundamentally flawed.

Comment: not all services offer OAuth.. this is really way to broad t go on

Comment: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Key_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html